# Delphi keypress and keybd_event

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, keypress

I have 2 components. In the first one I write a keyboard character, I focuse the second then I use `keybd_event` to send the keyboard press (key down and key up). But if I press "o" I have `ord(Key)` which is 111 (OK for the ascii table). But `keybd_event` prints a `/`

```
procedure TAutoComplete.AutoCompleteKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
    iKeyValue: integer;
begin
    FXEdit.SetFocus;

    iKeyValue := ord(Key);

    keybd_event(iKeyValue, MapvirtualKey(iKeyValue, 0), 0, 0);
    keybd_event(iKeyValue, MapvirtualKey(iKeyValue, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
end;
```

How can I convert the "key" to a byte for `keybd_event`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you David. Sory for the documentation, english is not my first langage and I don't understand all.

So this code works fine :

```
procedure TAutoComplete.AutoCompleteKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
    Input    : TInput;
    InputList: TList<TInput>;
begin
    FXEdit.SetFocus;

    InputList := TList<TInput>.Create;
    try
        Input            := Default (TInput);
        Input.Itype      := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        Input.ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        Input.ki.wScan   := ord(Key);
        InputList.Add(Input);
        Input.ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        InputList.Add(Input);

        SendInput(InputList.Count, InputList.List[0], SizeOf(TInput));
    finally
        InputList.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: The `TList` is overkill when you can use an `array[0..1] of TInput` instead. A `TList` would make more sense if you are sending characters from a variable-length string instead, but even then I would opt for a dynamic `array of TInput` instead of a `TList`.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: David, your post show me the way, but not the solution. You explain that I must to use "sendInput". And in this post I write code and it work for all characters on keyup.

Comment: Not really. If you look at this answer, you will see that it does not address the root issue of the question that was asked. That is why I down voted it.

Answer (score 1):

That is to be expected. The [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx) function does not accept ASCII codes. It accepts [virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx). And `111` corresponds to `VK_DIVIDE`.

This information is stated clearly in the documentation for [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx). I suspect that you have not read this documentation closely. Now is the time to put straight that omission.

If you wish to fake a lower case `O`, you will need to ensure that <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> is off and then fake the input of virtual key code `$4F` which happens to be  `ord('O')`.

Finally, the other useful information that you will glean from the documentation for [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx) is that you should not call it at all. Instead you should call [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).